# java - (slick2D) Move Sprite Set Distance at Set Speed on Keypress

Tags: java, distance

So I've been trying to write a simple game where a character is moving using the statement

```
character1.x+=0.1f*delta
```

where delta is the time (in milliseconds) between frames. This works well when I want to move it every frame, but I want to be able to move it a set distance (50 pixels, or a single tile in my game) at that speed. Using for() loops makes it move the sprite at maximum speed, so I can't do that. It has to work on a single keypress, so they don't have to hold the key down.

Of course, I've barely done anything ever in Java, so there's probably a really stupidly simple solution that I'm missing. For now, I can just change it to instantaneous movement, but it looks really jerky. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you might want to add a keyListener yo your component.

```
    yourComponent.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter () { // Possibly your Frame
             @Override // Overrides the keyPressed event
             public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                  if ( e == YOUR_KEY_CODE ) { 
                       for( int var = 0; var < yourDistance; var ++ ){
                          yourSpriteComponent.x += 1;
                          try{
                             Thread.sleep(yourTimeInMilliSec);
                          } catch( Exception e ){
                             // Your catch block here
                          }
                       }
                  }

            }
    });
```

Where YOUR_KEY_CODE is the key that the user needs to be pressed in order to execute the for() loop. Key Codes can be found in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)